# import txt file to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to import a txt file from my pc to azure sql.

Right now I'm using the wizard in microsoft sql server managment and I can do it but I would like to import by sql query

Here a sample of txt file to import
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9axe12wx0pns6k/test%20file.txt?dl=0

I tried openrowset but it is not supported from azure anymore, bulkimport but didn't work, I tried it with python but I would like to do by sql

This is the table I created in azure sql, just id that will be primary key is int, other I left all varchar

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LT01_PROJECT](
    [ID         ] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Project Reporting Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Start Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [End Date  ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Project Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Project Division] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Transport Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status   ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Project Lock                        ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Shipments] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Gross Weight (kg)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Net Revenue    ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Net Sales Revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provisioned Net Expenses] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Overhead Net Expense] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Net Expense (Excluding Overhead)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Total Net Cost (Includes Provisioned Expenses)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Net Profit    ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Profit Margin] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ROI         ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated Net Revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated Net Cost] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated Net Profit] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated Profit Margin] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estimated ROI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Revenue Difference] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Expense Difference] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Outstanding Estimated Net Revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Outstanding Estimated Net Expense] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Combined Net Revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Combined Net Cost] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Combined Net Profit] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Combined Profit Margin] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Combined ROI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Pending Net Revenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Pending Net Expense] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Responsible Person      ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Team] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

I tried to use python,

```
 import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                       'Server=xspeddataexchange.database.windows.net;'
                       'Database=TEST;'
                       'Trusted_Connection=no;'
```

Now I can import just by sql wizard in microsft sql server managment studio,
expected import a file by query

Comment: When you import using the SQL wizard in SSMS it is actually creating an SSIS package for you. Why not use SSIS?

Comment: could you explain me in mor e detail i created a ssis package i try to open with notepad for see what actually code is using to do that but it is not looks sql

Comment: The only way I have ever opened an SSIS package is with [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017), but there may be other ways. This [tutorial](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-integration-services) on the basics of SSIS might be helpful to you as well.